# trouble shooting installing expo

Tags: node.js, npm

Trying to install npm install -g expo-cli expo and everytime I do this error shows
and I cant run expo init

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/qimed/.npm/_logs/2022-10-11T17_11_44_205Z-debug-0.log
```